# Lambda limitions in usage with runnables

Tags: java, lambda, task, runnable

I have this code :

```
Task.doTask(new Runnable(){
    int bound = 0;
    @Override
    public void run(){
        switch (bound){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                finishTask();
                break;
        }
        bound++;
    }
    });
```

I can put initiate `int` bound and use it as a progress bar easily with that

```
    Task.doTask(() ->{
        int bound = 0;
        switch (bound){
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                finishTask();
                break;
        }
        bound++;
    });
```

but with using lambda i can't initiate bound, therefore it is always `0`;

Comment: That's because the body of the lambda defines `run` method inside the instance of the `Runnable` that gets passed to the `doTask` metod.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 pieces of code you have included are **DIFFERENT** (not because of `lambda expressions`)

```
Task.doTask(new Runnable(){
 int bound = 0; // initialize the bound variable as 'global'
 @Override
 public void run(){
    switch (bound){ 
        case 0:
            break;
            case 1:
                finishTask();
                break;
    }
    bound++; // the `bound` variable is `shared` across run calls
}
});

Task.doTask(() ->{
    int bound = 0; // initialize the bound variable EVERY TIME you call it
    switch (bound){
        case 0:
            break;
            case 1:
                finishTask();
                break;
    }
    bound++; // this is useless - bound is always initialize to zero for EVERY CALL
});
```

Comment: The problem i am having is that bound is being initialized everytime using lambda, I want to use lambda, but have it initialize just once as the first example does

Comment: you can use the `bound` variable at class scope - allowing it to save its state whenever you make a change in your lambda expression

Comment: I guess that's one way to do it, but a will become a growing obstacle as the class grows

Comment: I agree.. as suggested by @blazs you should use the "old" way with runnable as a better practice in that case

Answer (score 2):

That's because the body of the lambda defines the `run` method inside the instance of the `Runnable` that gets passed to the `doTask` metod.

I wouldn't call this a limitation---lambdas are just a syntactic shorthand for passing instance of one-method classes.

If you need a member variable, use the old way, as you do in the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a mutable wrapper outside of your lambda, for example:

```
AtomicInteger bound = new AtomicInteger(0);
Task.doTask(() -> {
    switch (bound.get()){
        case 0:
            break;
            case 1:
                finishTask();
                break;
    }
    bound.incrementAndGet();
});
```

Comment: Does this have any benefit when compared to an `int` defined outside the *lambda* ?

Comment: I would rather not create a class variable

Comment: @Shashwat External variables referenced inside a lambda must be final or effectively final, meaning you wouldn't be able to modify an `int` defined outside the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You can read final variables in lambdas, but your `Runnable` has no state any more as ymz already pointed out. Lambdas can be used to easily write functions, but what you originally used is stateful.